# How to import chart.js 3+ into React application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts

I have a trouble importing chart.js into my application, while in version 2+ it was simple as:

```
import Chartjs from 'chart.js';
```

Now this doesn't work anymore.

```
Attempted import error: 'chart.js' does not contain a default export (imported as 'Chartjs').
```

Comment: did you ever find out what the issue was? Encountering the same issue myself atm. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have to import it like this:
`import { Chart } from 'chart.js';`

More information are available on:
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/integration.html

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I found the answer. You have to import everything by parts and then register it.

```
import { Chart, PieController, ArcElement, Legend, Tooltip, Title } from 'chart.js';

Chart.register(PieController, ArcElement, Title, Legend, Tooltip);
```